# How use \typeout argument with backslash in message?

Tags: logging

How does one include a command name, including its backslash, in the message issued by a `\typeout` command?

For example, I want to issue the message `>>> Using \cmd` to the log. How must the following be modified to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\typeout{>>> Using \cmd.}
\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document
```

Comment: `\string\cmd` or `\protect\cmd` depending on space

Comment: That did it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\string\cmd` or `\protect\cmd` depending on space requirements.